# Can you add HTML as a note on Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to annotate an excel sheet with notes.

[image]

I know I can add text to a Note, or display an image. Are there any other alternatives? Eg. showing some rendered HTML on hover.

Comment: Suggest you look on google, the first hit for "excel mouseover image" seems to do the trick..

Comment: Everybody doesn't get the same results in google.  I got this one.  https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1906-excel-shouw-image-on-mouseover.html  It doesn't seem to show how to render HTML in a comment.

Comment: @do might be the second, third or fourth…

Comment: Hi. I'm looking to use HTML or another text-based format because it'd be nice to be able to select the content of the note as text.